# How to filter a typed Spark Dataset using pattern matching

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I try to jump on the typed Dataset API but I'm stuck with filtering:

```
val ds: Dataset[(Int, Int)] = Seq((1,1)).toDS

ds.filter(ij => ij._1 > ij._2) // does work, but is not readable
ds.filter{case (i,j) => i<j} // does not work
```

> Error:(36, 14) missing parameter type for expanded function The
>   argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
>   Expected type was: ?

I don't understand why pattern matching does not work with filter, while it works fine with map:

```
ds.map{case (i,j) => i+j}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a bug : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19492 Tanks to Bodgan for the information

Answer (score 2):

Make it explicit:

```
ds.filter{x => x match { case (i,j) => i < j}}
```

Comment: Yes this works, but I'm still wondering why `filter` is different from `map`, although method signature is almost the same

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit more readable:

```
val ds: Dataset[(Int, Int)] = Seq((1,1)).toDS
ds.filter('_1 > '_2)
```

Note: you need to import spark.implicits._

Comment: Thanks, did not know that. But I don't think thats more readable at all